# How to send a PDF generated with genpdf to Response in Rust?

Tags: rust

I was studying Rust, and a didnt find any answer for this question.
I'm trying to send the generated PDF to Client, I'm using tokio + axum to make the API Rest and genpdf to generate the PDF. How can I make it?

This is my code:

```
async fn make_pdf() -> impl IntoResponse {
    let font_family = genpdf::fonts::from_files("./fonts", "Calibri", None)
        .expect("Failed to load font");
    let mut doc = genpdf::Document::new(font_family);
    doc.set_title("Test Title");
    let mut decorator = genpdf::SimplePageDecorator::new();
    decorator.set_margins(10);
    doc.set_page_decorator(decorator);

    doc.push(genpdf::elements::Text::new("First PDF Text"));

    let mut stream = Reade::new(doc.render(w).unwrap());

    let headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "application/pdf; charset=utf-8".parse().unwrap());
    headers.insert(header::CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"Cargo.pdf\"".parse().unwrap());


    let body = StreamBody::new(stream);

    Ok((headers, body))
}
```

I tried to stream it with tokio_util::io::ReaderStream but it returns me an error. I really dont know what to do

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/608#discussioncomment-1789020

Comment: It is better if you will add error test. It will make problem more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `doc.render()` looks like this:

```
pub fn render(self, w: impl Write) -> Result<(), Error>
```

It is expecting a parameter to write the bytes into (via the [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait) and doesn't return anything beyond a potential error. The simplest route would be to write into a `Vec<u8>` and then return that from your Axum handler:

```
let mut pdf_bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
doc.render(&mut pdf_bytes).unwrap(); // TODO: handle error properly

// ... headers ...

Ok((headers, pdf_bytes))
```

Note: if `.render()` takes long to run, it'd be better to use tokio's [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) to process it separately from the `async` environment. Note: your code had a couple other errors (no `mut` on `headers`, unclear `Ok` when returning `impl IntoResponse`) but I won't elaborate on fixing those.

Comment: thanks about it! It solved my problem